# How to get my ASP.NET to work after changing from Debug to Release in the TFS Build Definition?

Tags: asp.net, tfs, build-process, release, tfsbuild

I have a build that drops my asp.net project over to Windows Server 2003.

It works fine when the Configurations to Build setting is set to Debug. Configurations to Build setting can be found on the Process tab when editing the Build Definition

But when I change the setting to Release, I get the following error from the browser:

*Could not load file or assembly 'Assembly.XmlSerials' or one of its dependencies. This assembly is built by a runtime newer than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.*

**Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix this?**

Comment: Can you run the project locally on your development machine in Release configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Load your solution in Visual studio. Right click on the solution file and click on Configuration Manager. Check waht is checked for Configuration and platform and whether to build. then change the active solution to release. Make sure you have the same settings for release as you do for Debug. Judging by the error message i would suggest that debug and release are different and release may by targetting a different platform for one of your projects. Save the solution file and check back in to source control

Comment: I changed the solution to release like you mentioned but I got the same error unfortunately.

Comment: was the configuration and platform different for Release to what was set for Debug?

Comment: In the configuration manager the configuration were all set to 'Release', the Platform was set to 'Any CPU' and the Active solution platform was set to 'Mixed Platforms'. The only thing I changed was setting the configuration all to 'Release'.

Comment: I'd check the mixed platforms one, is that set the same for Debug? your error message is saying that you have a problem with platform, ANYCPU v Mixed Platforms sounds like the issue.

Comment: Yes it was the same for Debug (is it normal that those setting actually worked for debug?) - Unfortunately I am not able to mess around with the builds for the next couple of days, but will try this solution when I next get a chance.